# Unity - warning: animations neck and head have scale

Tags: unity, animation, import, importing

I always get this warning if I import my model to unity:

[image]

```
Clip 'soldier_idle' has import animation warnings that might lower retargeting quality:

Note: Activate translation DOF on avatar to improve retargeting quality:

    'neck' has scale animation that will be discared.

    'head' has scale animation that will be discared.
```

Even though there are in fact no scale animations on the bones `neck` and `head` as you can see in my blender dopesheet.

[image]

So why is this warning showing?

Comment: I have the same issue in 2019. Did you manage to find the cause?

Comment: I had to quit the project because I had no time.